# recently viewed pages using session

Tags: php, session, hyperlink

so the code i have for gathering the recently viewed pages is

```
<?php
session_start();
$currentpageurl = $_GET['username'];
$_SESSION['pageurl'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if( count( $_SESSION['pageurl'] ) > 10 ){
array_shift( $_SESSION['pageurl'] );
}
foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

and the code for displaying it is

```
<?php
session_start();

foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

the problem is that i need the url to be clickable at the moment it just displays the url as text: 
The value of $_SESSION['0'] is 'localhost/works.php'

how would i go about making it linkable

Comment: tried wrapping it in `<a/>` html tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SESSION['0'].'">Click here</a>';
```

Comment: sorry i don't think i was very clear what i meant is 
The value of $_SESSION['0'] is 'localhost/works.php' is getting displayed and i need the localhost/works.php to be hyperlinked

Comment: Never mind i was being dumb :P
    <?php
    session_start();

    foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<a href="'.$value.'">Click here</a>';
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".']" is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';

    }
    ?>
that's the code working thanks a lot man